# How to list the column index of a table in excel that contains a given value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to list all column indexes of a table in Excel with a given value.

I use function `MATCH` but it only shows the first column they found.
Some people tell me use `OFFSET` inside the `MATCH` function but I don't know how to do it.

Example with picture is shown here. I want to write a formula which show result like `MARK` column:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3fc2.png)

Comment: Not sure what you want. Show an example with enough detail so we can see what you want to achieve.

Comment: i have upload example of my excel i want to do. pls help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly based on your example this should work:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(B2:F2="x",$B$1:$F$1,""))
```

`B2:F2` is range in same row with "x" in it

`$B$1:$F$1` is the header row

Basically what it does is it will replace all headers that don't have "x" with blank values and join all headers without blank values together